# c++ constructor - How to initiate without new?

Tags: c++, constructor

So I am trying to create a class that is consisted of two stacks. I want to create a constructor for it, and I want the stacks initially to have 0 elements in them:

```
class twoStacks {
    std::stack<int> mins;
    std::stack<int> values;
    twoStacks():
    {
    }
};
```

When I compile this, I get an error, "error: expected class member or base class name." Why can't I have an empty constructor? (I'm using clang-600.0.56)

Do I need a constructor in the first place, seeing as I just want to initiate empty stacks? Would this cause issues when I push elements onto the stacks?

Is there a guideline on how to structure a class like this? By this I mean, should I use two pointers to stacks instead? If I used pointers, I would initiate with the `new` keyword. Which way is preferred?

For example, if this class had another member variable/value `int size`, I would list initiate it to 0. But what do I do when it's a container? I am assuming if there is a convection, it would be the same whether they are stacks, vectors, or any other container(correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: You don't need the constructor at all. Implicitly-defined default constructor already does what you want.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Got it. Are there any situations where I should not do this? If I do `new` on twoStacks, the specific instance would all be on the heap right?

Comment: I do not at all understand the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are required to write correct code if you don't wish the compiler to reward you with an error message.

Remove the colon after `twoStacks()` and before the `{`.

Or add valid initialisers to default construct the members

```
twoStacks(): mins(), values()
{
}
```

or (since the compiler will generate a default constructor for you, in most circumstances in which you have not declared another constructor), simply remove the declaration and definition of the constructor completely.

Comment: I removed the colon and it compiled. Thanks. Is there any situation where I should use a pointer instead (and thus initiate the stacks with `new`)? My instinct is that I can use `new` on the entire class, and both stacks would then be on the heap (thus no need to creating the two stacks on the heap individually)

Comment: No need to "initiate the stacks with `new`" in C++.  Operator `new` in C++ is used to dynamically create objects, not to default initialise objects (although operator `new` can be used to dynamically create a default-initialised object). The fact you're thinking that way says you're trying to use techniques from another language (I'm guessing C# or Java), in which operator `new` is the preferred technique to default construct an object. Get out of the habit of thinking that way - there are too many techniques that are good practice in other languages but bad practice in C++ - and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Although ironically I have never used C# or Java. I just remember that the `new` operator creates the object on the heap instead of the stack, so I wanted to clarify what was the preferred way of doing things in a class. Thank you for your explanation, I learned a lot.

Comment: Advice that advocates using the heap is decades old, and only rarely applicable now.   Look up techniques like RAII - objects should manage the lifetime of their own resources.

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the colon after `twoStacks()`. Unless you explicitly call the constructor on member variables, the compiler will generate code to default construct them.

Comment: Thanks, It compiled without the colon.